# I'm getting a gas limit error when calling ethers web3js on a view/ read-only blockchain function

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}, method="call" code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT) error.

I am definitely calling a read-only function. The function is this:

```
function vaultSize(uint256 vaultId) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
    return
        store.isD2Vault(vaultId)
            ? store.d2Holdings(vaultId)
            : store.holdingsLength(vaultId).add(
                store.reservesLength(vaultId)
            );
}
```

If that matters. I don't understand why this gas limit error is even happening or how to fix it and I feel like debugging is so hard when it's not my own contract because the revert reason is never obvious.

Here's how I'm calling it in javascript.

```
await contract.vaultSize(0)
```

I don't see why this is happening. This is public code in a contract that is obviously working with thousands of transactions a day.

The address is "0xdaa17a5f60E94d5f97968aa1E790c164e65c97Be"

Comment: Please edit your question with minimal **reproducible** code example that throws the error.

Comment: I thought this was it. I mean I don't want someone to have to deploy an entire contract just to also have this bug. But my whole code is just calling that contract's vaultSize method and it's not working. Should I just share the contract address to see if anyone else can call it in the same way with ethers?

Comment: If the contract is already deployed on a public network, the address should be sufficient.

Comment: Okay I added it. It's "0xdaa17a5f60E94d5f97968aa1E790c164e65c97Be";

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue with `web3.js`, which means that the error origins from contract (not from your JS implementation).

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonAbi, '0xdaa17a5f60E94d5f97968aa1E790c164e65c97Be');
const result = await contract.methods.vaultSize(0).call(); // throws "execution reverted"
```

---

The Solidity code expects the `store` address to implement the `IXStore`, but the value of `store` is `0x0`. There's no contract on the zero address.

So when the contract calls `store.isD2Vault(vauldId)`, it expects a `bool` response, but it doesn't get any. So the call fails.

**Solution: Set the `store` value to an implementation of an `IXStore` interface and this revert will be solved.**

Note that it's a large set of contracts, so if it's not properly tested, it's probable that there's more logical errors that might cause other reverts.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for checking it out. I know the code is super long and complex. Although it being broken is confusing because this function is called successfully hundreds of times a week by other functions in the contract. Is this contract not failing because it is the implementer of a proxy contract? The proxy https://etherscan.io/address/0xAf93fCce0548D3124A5fC3045adAf1ddE4e8Bf7e# calls this function. Is that somehow giving the "store" variable a value that I can't access by calling the implementer directly? Their web3 site seems to function.

Comment: I just change my code to use the same ABI but use the address of the proxy instead and now it works! I should've thought of that earlier. I looked at the proxy code and it seems like it's messing with the storage somehow in a way that doesn't change the storage when called directly like I was just doing. Not sure how that works but I suppose I should find resources on proxy memory stuff to read! Thanks again man :) You're great.

Comment: When a proxy delegates a call, it's using bytecode of the implementation (in your case the `0xdaa17...`) but storage of the proxy. And the storage of the proxy might have the value set... So what you're saying about the proxy, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, and I solved it by removing the `gas` property from the contract ABI.

For example, part of my ABI looked like this:

```json
{
  "name": "get_virtual_price",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "type": "uint256",
      "name": ""
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function",
  "gas": 1011891
}
```

And I modified it to look like this, just removed `gas`:

```json
{
  "name": "get_virtual_price",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "type": "uint256",
      "name": ""
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}
```

Surprisingly enough, `ethers` was happy and didn't complain about being out of gas after that.